# How to open WorkItem (VS-Team Explorer) from outside visual studio?

Tags: c#, tfs

I want to open the workitem from outside visual studio using C# code. is it possible?

I tried with this :

```
IWorkItemDocument widoc = null;
try
{
    string tfsName = "http://rd-tfs-no2:8080/tfs/siproducts";
    var projectCollectionUri = new Uri(tfsName);

    var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(projectCollectionUri, new UICredentialsProvider());
    projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
    DocumentService docService = (DocumentService)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DocumentService));
    widoc = docService.GetWorkItem(projectCollection, id,this);
    docService.ShowWorkItem(widoc);
}
finally
{
    widoc.Release(this);
}
```

But help less Im getting null value for docService.

Any good suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The `Package` only works when you are working on a Visual Studio plug-in.  If you're looking for a way to display the work item, you could either do it by mapping fields to your winform/WPF application, or by shelling out to Internet Explorer and passing the work item ID into the URL for the web-based viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try looking at the WorkItemStore object in the TFS API.

```
        TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(Constants.TEAMFOUNDSERVER);
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
        string wiqlQuery = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems";
        WorkItemCollection wic = workItemStore.Query(wiqlQuery);
        foreach (WorkItem wi in wic) 
        {
             //do work here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the document service, try this:

```
var dte2 = Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0") as DTE2;
var witDocumentService = (DocumentService)dte2.DTE.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.DocumentService");
```

Comment: Im getting error at secound line of your statement - Cannot convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.DocumentService'.